# Setting and Getting of Values using Scala Reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I have a `patient` resource of below type:

```
val p:Patient = new Patient
```

which comes under below package:

```
import org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Patient
```

Now, I want to `set` some value for it like one `ID` attribute with value like `example` and when I try something like `p.getId()` I should be able to retrieve it. I was trying `scala reflection` and desgined below methods by referring one of the posts but not sure how to use it over here. Below are the methods for `get` and `set`:

```
object PatientInvoker {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Patient").master("local[1]").getOrCreate()
    val patientOutput = "C:\\Users\\siddheshk2\\IdeaProjects\\fhir\\mapper\\src\\main\\resources\\patientOutput.json"
    val idValue = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(patientOutput).select(col("id")).first.getString(0)

    implicit def reflector(ref: AnyRef) = new {
      def getV(name: String): Any = ref.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == name).get.invoke(ref)

      def setV(name: String, value: Any): Unit = ref.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == name + "_$eq").get.invoke(ref, value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
    }

    val p: Patient = new Patient
    p.setV("id", idValue)
    println("id:" + p.getV("id"))
  }
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at com.fhir.mapper.io.PatientInvoker$$anon$1.setV(StudentInvoker.scala:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Unable to set value of `idValue` using reflector method. Please guide me through it

Comment: You have a `None`, an empty `Option`, so there is no element to get. I assume that you get this exception after calling `getMethods.find(...).get`. This just means that there's no method with that name. The `find` method returns an `Option`

Comment: What do you suggest over here?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything. I don't know much about Spark, and I don't know how you can fix it. All I can tell is that there is no method named `id_$eq` in the `Patient` class

Comment: There does seem to be a [`setIdentifier`](https://github.com/hapifhir/org.hl7.fhir.core/blob/344d778a87d446f36717c9f895a854eec762fbb6/org.hl7.fhir.r4/src/main/java/org/hl7/fhir/r4/model/Patient.java#L1363) method in the Java source file I found on GitHub

Comment: I am also new to this API. Can you suggest some code level changes with some layman explanation

Comment: First of all, this is a Java API, as far as I can tell, so you can't expect to have methods like `id_=` there. Also, wouldn't it be better to just use `setIdentifier` and `getIdentifier`, unless your actual problem is more complex than just setting id's?

Comment: Yes, I want to set and get attributes for an FHIR resource. Any other API which I can use for this purpose?